# Not passing arguments correctly

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile a 64 bit executable, and whenever I debug it I see that it's not correctly passing values:

```
char buf[1024];
nret = recv(sock, buf, 1024, 0);

if( nret == 0 ) 
    break;

SOCKET s = sock;
char *ptr = buf;
int len = nret;
HandleReceive(s, ptr, len);
```

On handlereceives stack, it's saying that ptr is a bad pointer, and all of the values are completely messed up! They're not what they were before the function was called.  What can I do to fix this?

Yes, I use visual studios debugger.  I've even tried passing a set value of 0x1000 for ptr.  It doesn't get this value either.

I'm compiling as debug.

The function is extremely long, but here is what it is:

```
void HandleReceive(SOCKET sock, char *buf, int len)
{
    using namespace Socket;

    if( _internal_safecmp(buf, HELLO, strlen(HELLO)) )
    {
        echo("hello");

    }   
}
```

I've debugged the code the problem is its not accessing values correctly.

It will pass a value in rcx but then expect that same valued passed to be in r10... so it has to be a bug with the compiler.  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You compile and link with debug information? Without it, the debugger can only make educated guesses while examining the stack.

Comment: Yes, you use the debugger, but do you compile as "Debug" or as "Release"?

Comment: your code makes no sense,.. .where is the function?

Comment: what are the details of HandleRecieve function?

Comment: Is there a correct prototype for `HandleReceive()` seen by the code that's calling it? This is especially important if the language being used is C instead of C++ since all you'll get from the compiler is a warning by default.

Comment: Are you talking about `sock` or `buf` argument? AFAIK, `buf` should be passes in RDX and `sock` in RCX. Maybe the calling conventions are mismatched in declaration and definition?